# In Bayesian terminology, what does evidence refer to?

Tags: bayesian, terminology

In Bayes theorem of a parameter $\theta$ with data $D$, we have:

$$P(\theta|D) = \frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(D)}$$

where I know $P(D)$ as the marginal likelihood. Is it true that the marginal likelihood is referred to as evidence in Bayesian statistics? If not what is commonly refered to as evidence?

Comment: The "evidence" would be $D$ itself and not its marginal distribution $P(D)$.

Comment: It is correct that the term evidence is sometimes used as a substitute for marginal likelihood, or marginal density. See for instance [Skilling (2006)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1340370944).

Answer (score 7):

$P(D)$ is the *model evidence*, unfortunately "model" is often dropped. The model evidence is also referred to as *marginal likelihood*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) calls the data $D$ the *evidence*.

The *model evidence* is defined as:

$\int\,P(D,\theta)d\theta = P(D)$

It is called the *model* evidence, since the larger its value, the more apt the model is generally fitting the data.

Answer (score 2):

The term are loosely defined.

In your question, We use the term **data** ($D$) and **parameter** ($\theta$).

In other literature, people use another set of terms: **evidence** ($E$) and **hypothesis** ($H$), which are exactly the same thing to your $D$ and $\theta$.

Using the evidence and hypothesis combo, following notation is also widely used.

$$P(H|E) = \frac{P(E|H)P(H)}{P(E)}$$

Check the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) on Bayesian Inference, you can see the formula.

Comment: It seems the answer needs editing, see comment by @Xian above.